# Charm 4.0.1 DatePicker unwanted white frame

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

After the update to Charm 4.0.1 there is an unwanted white frame around the `DatePicker`:

[image]

It seems to be caused by the padding of the `VBox` which contains the `DatePicker.content`. 
Setting css via stylesheet, didn't change the padding, so my only solution so far has been the following:

```
public class DatePickerFrameless extends DatePicker {

    public DatePickerFrameless(LocalDate date) {
        super(date);

        rootNode.visibleProperty().addListener((obsValue, b, b1) -> {
            if (b1) {
                VBox container = (VBox) rootNode.lookup(".container");
                container.setStyle("-fx-padding:0;");
            }
        } );
    }

}
```

Is there a more convenient way to get rid of the frame?

**EDIT:**

Setting css via stylesheet works:

```
.dialog > .container {
    -fx-padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I've filed an issue, so it can be fixed as soon as possible. Your fix seems correct, though use `.charm-date-picker` instead of `.dialog` so you just modify the date picker.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

I used this rule to change the blue background into white but doesn't work! Can u help me?

.charm-date-picker > .header {
        -fx-background-color: #ffffff; 
    }